# Recommended Emacs for ORG-Mode (vanilla, emacs plus, doom, spacemacs)? Getting Things Done (GTD) Method?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture

This is just a general question in relation to emacs and it's specific use for ORG mode.
I have always been miserable at planning and organization in daily life (keeping TODO list, general time management), and after having found emacs and org-mode a month ago, I am excited seeing its potential.

Clearly emacs is extremely configurable and everyones situation differs, but does anyone have any advice on a methodology (such as GTD) to follow that has proven successful for you, and flavour of emacs installation is recommended? (I do not have vim experience so I assume spacemacs or doom is not the place to start).

Comment: Welcome to emacs.stackexchange.com which primarily focuses on just one unique question per thread, and has a finite number of correct answers.  Your question is better suited to https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ where everyone has at least one opinion regarding the matters discussed .... there are hard core GTD users over there as well as some calendar variations.

Comment: ok thanks for that i will check out redit

Comment: @lawlist is correct. If I may venture to add my two penny's worth: vanilla Emacs is the place to start.